# java : How to create a method that can compare speed info of two objects

Tags: java, methods

HI: I am working on my project. 
The method requires: call the compare method of the first Car object, this method accepts another Car object as input, compares their speeds and displays one of the following messages as appropriate

I set a class of car,and have two car objects (each has the speed attribute), but I don't know how to set a method of the 1st car can compare these two.

And I haven't learned array yet, so I am sure this method is not about array.

I will appreciate if anyone can help me!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: actually i read the tutorial already , but I didn't find what I am looking for, give me some tips please, I don't have any idea about that...

Comment: i am not asking u guys to do the basic program for me , I just want to study, just want to learn the way of think when program and very appreciate the kind people who helping me ,am I wrong? if u don't like what i did, just don't leave any comments. actually from this post, I learned I can use object to be the parameter, is it specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Car{
    protected long speed=0;
    public String compareSpeed(Car anotherCar){
        if (this.speed > anotherCar.speed ) return "Faster";
        if (this.speed < anotherCar.speed ) return "Slower";
        return "Same Speed";
    }
    public void setSpeed(long speed){
        this.speed=speed;
    }
}

public static void main(){
    Car firstCar = new Car();
    Car secondCar = new Car();

    firstCar.setSpeed(10);
    secondCar.setSpeed(20);

    System.out.println(firstCar.compareSpeed(secondCar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create a compare method:

1. write a method in your Car class that takes a Car object as input:

   public boolean isMoreSpeedy(Car car)
2. assuming that your Car class has a method that returns speed as an integer here is the comparison part

   return this.getSpeed() > car.getSpeed();
3. just two line method that will tell you which car object has more speedy than you can print any message based on returned boolean

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks !! I don't know can use another object to be the parameter, thank u !! help a lot, thank you all !!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Car implements Comparable {
    private int speed;

    public Car(int s) {
        speed = s;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Car other = (Car) o;
        return this.speed - other.speed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class car{

public int speed;

public compareSpeed(car a){
if(a.speed==this.speed){
System.out.println("same speed")
}else
System.out.println("different speed")
```

Create a compare method in one of the class which accepts a variable of same class type

then call the method using the object as below.

```
public static void main(Sring[] args){

car c1=new car();
c1.speed=10;
car c2=new car();
c2.speed=20;

c1.compare(c2);

}
```

}

Comment: You really shouldn't just give the answer to the OP on something this simple.

Comment: And your code does not compile.